# 4x4 magic square consisting of consecutive composite numbers

Tags: magic-square

Is it possible to create a fourth-order magic square consisting of consecutive composite numbers that don't form an arithmetic sequence? If possible, give an example . If not, provide a proof.

**Clarification:**

In case someone is not sure what consecutive composite numbers are, here is an example: 4, 6, 8, 9 and 10 are five consecutive composite numbers because they are all the composite numbers from 4 to 10 and they are listed in order.

Comment: Doesn't every set of consecutive numbers form an arithmetic sequence? Or do you mean that for example 4 and 6 are consecutive because we're only looking at composite numbers?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis See edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible.

First start with the following standard magic square.

> ```
> 8  11 14 1
> 13 2  7  12
> 3  16 9  6
> 10 5  4  15
> ```

You can then transform it by

> decrementing the numbers 1 to 8

which gives the following magic square which is not in arithmetic progression:

> ```
> 7  11 14 0
> 13 1  6  12
> 2  16 9  5
> 10 4  3  15
> ```

Now we just need to add the right number to make them all composite:

> It has numbers 0-7 and 9-16, missing number 8. We need to find a prime p with a [prime gap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap) of at least 9 on both sides, and then add p-8. This makes the missing number the prime p, and all the other numbers composite. The first such prime is 211.

This gives the final answer:

> ```
> 210   214   217   203
> 216   204   209   215
> 205   219   212   208
> 213   207   206   218
> ```

This has magic constant

> 844